# Concurrent collection for .NET with timeouts?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency, timeout

I have a concurrent collection.

```
var q = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(); // Or a stack/bag/etc...
```

I can get an item like this.

```
int i;
if (q.TryDequeue(out i))
    DoStuff(i);
```

But I need it like "wait 10 seconds before returning false in case someone adds a new item":

```
int i;
if (q.TryDequeue(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), out i))
    DoStuff(i);
```

I could write an extension method like this:

```
public static bool TryDequeue<T>(
    this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue,
    TimeSpan timeout,
    out T result)
{
    // Validations...

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
            return true;
        else if (i == 1)
            return false;

        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
    }
}
```

But what if someone adds an item to the queue in 5 seconds, I don't want to wait 5 more.

Is there any thread-safe collection that supports this feature in .NET?

Comment: This sounds in theory like a fit for [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). It is possible to do time-based polling if memory serves. Not sure what the multi-threaded support is like though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than use `ConcurrentQueue` directly, you should wrap it in a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). You can then use [`TryTake(out T, TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287247.aspx).

`BlockingCollection` is specifically designed for producer/consumer scenarios. (You should look at [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) at the same time, mind you.)

Comment: Jon, is this answer still valid,  I started using BlockingCollection and now started facing issue with that due to thread blocking.  Any other suggestions you have for .Net Framework like "Channels" (which seems to be .Net core specific)

Comment: @Gopichandar: Yes, the answer is still valid - but there could be any number of things that cause blocking issues. I suggest you ask a new question that includes a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @jon,  I have added one with samples.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123617/issue-with-blockingcollection-in-c-sharp-net-framework