# Issue with BlockingCollection in C# (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, publish-subscribe

### Setup

1. Let say I need to build an application that needs to serve 100+ users simultaneously with some data every 800ms
2. If there is no data for 800ms I need to send an heartbeat to clients that service is alive.

### Experiment

I'm trying to achieve this with `BlockingCollection` of C#.  Here is the sample

#### UserClass

```
    class EachUserClass
    {
        public EachUserClass()
        {
            id = incrementer++;
            Task.Run(() => StartProcessing());
        }
        private static int incrementer = 0;
        private int id = 0;
        BlockingCollection<string> collection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        public void StartProcessing()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var incoming = "";
                if (collection.TryTake(out incoming, 800))
                {
                    //
                }
                else
                {
                    if(id == 99)
                        Console.WriteLine( DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Timeout on " + id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### MainProgram

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App started at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                new EachUserClass();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

#### Output

```
App started at: 16-04-2021 15:45:37
16-04-2021 15:47:08 - Timeout on 99
16-04-2021 15:47:09 - Timeout on 99
16-04-2021 15:47:10 - Timeout on 99
```

#### Observation

You can see there there is huge delay between AppStart and sending timeout to 99th user.   This is because I'm trying to launch 100 tasks on the thread-pool in very quick succession.

[image: Threads Count]

Any suggestion's to run it asynchronously.

Comment: "This is because of Thread are being blocked by BlockingCollection as Name suggest." Are you absolutely sure about that? Are you *sure* it's not because you're trying to launch 100 tasks on the thread-pool in very quick succession? I suggest you log when each task starts, as the first line of `StartProcessing`. I suspect you'll find task 99 doesn't start for a long time, because the thread pool ramps up slowly.

Comment: @JonSkeet , Im not absolutely sure on that statement. Will give I try on your suggestion.

Comment: You are right @JonSkeet the delay is because of launch,  but it shouldn't be Right?  ThreadPool should manage this as Threads are ideal in Timeout.  Also, I can see Threads Count shows `108` which seems to be Huge.  So it was creating new one instead of utilizing the same.  I don't know is there a way.  But I acheived this in .NetCore with `Channels` which uses  less that 10 threads for the same sample but I need it for Framework.

Comment: How would you expect it to use fewer threads? You're starting 100 tasks, and each of those is running synchronously. The thread pool is geared towards running a lot of *short-lived* tasks, but your tasks aren't short-lived. The expectation is that adding a new thread to the thread pool should be a relatively rare event. You can ask it to keep a particular number of threads available, or speed up the thread creation process, but its default behavior is reasonable for the expected use. I suggest you read the ThreadPool docs really carefully.

Comment: [System.Threading.Channels](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels) NuGet package, available for .NET Framework 4.6 and later.

Comment: Use TaskFactory.StartNew() so you can specify TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_StartNew_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_

Comment: @JonSkeet, Idea is to wait Asyncronously on timeout that will fix all the problems I hope but Blocking collection wont help here I think. Let me try `System.Threading.Channels` for framework suggested by @theodor